# Swift protocols with mutually recursive associated type constraints in a function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Is it possible to constrain two generic parameters associated types in a function to each other?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
protocol One {
    associatedtype first: Two
}

protocol Two {
    associatedtype second: One
}

func f<O: One, T: Two>(o: O) -> T where O.first == T, T.second == O {
    fatalError()
}
```

It fails with the errors:

```
'first' is not a member type of 'O'

'second' is not a member type of 'T'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this compile by removing one of the constraints on the function:

```
func f<O: One, T>(o: O) -> T where O.first == T, T.second == O {
    fatalError()
}
```

You don't need to say that `T` conforms to `Two` because that's already implied by `O.first == T` (because `O.first` must conform to `Two`). Once I took that out, this compiled.

Comment: Nice, it worked! Guess it's a bug on the language though, as specifying the type is redundant but should be allowed AFAIK

Comment: Yeah I got some "redundant conformance" warnings in addition to the warnings you mentioned so I tried removing those first, and suddenly it just worked after I removed that one thing. I agree it seems like a bug, I think.